# Javascript onload event not work on div layer

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, onload-event

I've a DIV tag layer, which is not visible on loading, but show on a click.

I'm loading a few photos also to this layer, but when I use the onload event, the photos invisible, just the space of them show. When I try to use the onclick event, I show the photo and can use the image viewer script, but its not really elegant for me.

Here is my code, where I try to use this javascript image viewer, 2 differemt method (zoom, etc):http://www.spictrading.com/viewer/home.php#what-next

```
echo '<img src="./tmp/';
     echo $_GET['leolv_biz_id'];
     echo '_'.$sor.'.jpg" ';
     echo 'style="width:800px;" onclick="new viewer({image: this,frame: [\'800px\',\'450px\']});"/>'; //
     echo '<br>';


     echo ' <script type="text/javascript">
    var viewerObject = new viewer({
    parent: document.getElementById(\'light'.$k.'\'),
    imageSource: \'./tmp/'.$_GET['leolv_biz_id'].'_'.$sor.'.jpg\',
    frame: [\'400px\',\'250px\'] 
});
</script>';
```

What's wrong with the onload event, and how can I solve it, because the onclick event works good?

Comment: Can you give me a Demo please ?

Comment: please do not link you external sites other than [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.com) or similar to demonstrate your issue. Ones your link is dead or the page has changed, it has no use to future users with similar issue. Also, where is that `onload` event binding  code you speak of?

Comment: I tried to use onload instead of onclick in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are feeding data to javascript through PHP, and the PHP may not have finished parsing before the javascript has begun executing.  Have you tried the Firebug console?  What feedback does it give you?

Comment: I'll try it monday. (We prefer to use IE, but I've Firefox also, I'll try to setup firebug -I'm not admin on my computer.)

Comment: It's very difficult to code javascript without some form of a javascript console.  By the way, you might want to consider moving away from embedding php into javascript code.  A good starting point might be jQuery .ajax.  You can setup jQuery by searching for "google jquery".  Google will actually give you the one line of code you need to use jQuery.  The ajax request will ask a php page to do or get something, and jquery's success method will listen and respond at the appropriate time.  If you decide to give it a try, I think you're going to like it.

Comment: Onload produce this code part:

`code`<div style="width: 800px; height: 450px; border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; z-index: 2;" tabindex="1">
<img width="0" height="0" onload="new viewer({image: this,frame: ['800px','450px']});" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border-width: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 3; left: 0px; top: 0px; cursor: crosshair;" src="./tmp/257158917_2.jpg">
</div>

Comment: Onclick:

`code`<div style="width: 800px; height: 450px; border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; z-index: 2;" tabindex="1">
<img width="338" height="450" onclick="new viewer({image: this,frame: ['800px','450px']});" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border-width: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 3; left: 231px; top: 0px; cursor: crosshair;" src="./tmp/257158917_2.jpg">
</div>

Comment: May the problem is, the php create the image file before the onload script, and the file haven't finished before the javascript starting?